# java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList - cast List to ArrayList

Tags: java, jpa

I have following code

```
public List<Item> getDbItems()
    {
        ArrayList<Item> dbItems = new ArrayList<>();
        EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
            entr.begin();
        TypedQuery<Item> query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Item i", Item.class);
        dbItems = (ArrayList<Item>) query.getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return dbItems;
    }
```

And I need it to return the ArrayList instead of the Array. Is there an query that returns ArrayList?

Comment: What's your point for that `ArrayList` cast? Why don't you use the more obivous `(List<Item>)`?

Comment: *I need it to return the ArrayList* - no you don't

Comment: I think this all boils down to inheritance 101 and coding to an interface.

Comment: bit more information will help to provide solution.

Comment: Why is `java.util.Vector` mentioned in the headline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
dbItems = (ArrayList<Item>) query.getResultList();
```

to this:

```
dbItems = new ArrayList<Item>(query.getResultList());
```

Now, from a design perspective, clients of your method should decide which kind of implementation they want to use, use abstractions/interfaces whenever possible. Forget about ArrayList, just use List all around your query method, and then clients of your method will have to decide how to use that List and which implementation they want.

Also, you don't need a transaction for a single SELECT query

```
public List<Item> getDbItems()
    { 
        TypedQuery<Item> query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Item i", Item.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what an Interface and a Class is:

- The Interface here is List, it will provide to you the set of functions/methods you can call.
- The Class you will instance, in this case ArrayList, you say to you ***how*** the methods provided for the interface List will be executed, so now, to your code can compile, and well function, do:

  ```
  public List<Item> getDbItems()
  {
      List<Item> dbItems = new ArrayList<>();
      EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
          entr.begin();
      TypedQuery<Item> query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Item i", Item.class);
      dbItems = query.getResultList();
      em.getTransaction().commit();
      return dbItems;
  }
  ```